# How does the ring of mystic fire interact with scorching ray?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items

In my *D&D 3.5* campaign, one PC just got a *ring of mystic fire*, and I'm trying to figure out how the *ring* works with the spell *scorching ray*.

The *Magical Item Compendium* says

> A *ring of mystic fire* provides a boost to your fire-based spells. When casting spells with the fire descriptor, you gain a +1 competence bonus to caster level. This is a continuous effect and requires no activation. The ring has 3 charges, renewed daily at dawn. **Spending 1 or more charges grants a bonus to the amount of damage you deal with the next fire spell you cast before the end of your turn.** (If the spell doesn't normally deal fire damage, this expenditure has no effect).
>
> - 1 charge:  +2d6 fire damage
> - 2 charges: +3d6 fire damage
> - 3 charges: +4d6 fire damage

My player intends to use all 3 charges for +4d6 fire damage with the *scorching ray* spell, which says

> You blast your enemies with fiery rays. You may fire one ray, plus one additional ray for every four levels beyond 3rd (to a maximum of three rays at 11th level). Each ray requires a ranged touch attack to hit and deals 4d6 points of fire damage.
>
> The rays may be fired at the same or different targets, but all bolts must be aimed at targets within 30 feet of each other and fired simultaneously.

My question is this: Does the *ring of mystic fire* grant the character a +4d6 fire damage per ray? I'm inclined to rule that the *ring* does add its damage to each ray, but that risks making the spell overpowered, even though it is only once per day. And, even if overpowered, I prefer to rule in favor of what makes sense.

Answer (score 15):

## The *ring of mystic fire* only affects the upcoming spell once

The *ring of mystic fire* (*Magic Item Compendium* 125) (7,500 gp; 0 lbs.) does, indeed, grant "a bonus to the amount of damage you deal with the next fire spell you cast before the end of your turn," but the *ring* only grants that bonus *once*. Each ray of a *scorching ray* spell isn't the spell; instead, the *whole* spell creates *multiple* rays. The *ring* improves the spell's damage only *once* by a maximum of +4d6 no matter how many effects result from the *ring*-modified spell.

(Ruling that each ray of the *scorching ray* spell benefits from the *ring* multiplies the power of the *ring* by the number of rays—with rather extreme consequences at low levels, especially given that the *ring* increases *also* the wearer's caster level for fire spells!)

Although the DM has several options available to adjudicate the *ring*'s effect—allowing the player to distribute the total number of extra dice damage the *ring* grants among the rays before (or even after) the rays're launched, for instance—, this DM would keep things simple and have the player add the extra damage to his PC's *first* ray in a volley from the spell *scorching ray*, in much the same way that precision damage applies to the first attack in a similar volley (*Rules Compendium* 42). (In fact, I have a fire wizard in a current campaign who's eyeing this very item, and that's how I'm ruling it works.)

Hence, for example, under such a ruling, a level 6 caster wearing a *ring of mystic fire* can take a swift action to spend 3 of the *ring*'s charges. Then the caster can cast *scorching ray*, creating 2 rays (because of the increase in caster level granted by the *ring*) and making 2 ranged touch attacks. If the first ray hits, it deals 8d6 points of fire damage. If the second ray hits, it deals 4d6 points of fire damage.

Comment: What about fireball? Would you also apply it against first target only?

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski No. The spell [*fireball*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsFtoG.html#fireball) isn't targeted, affects an area, and creates only that one effect per typical casting. That extra +4d6 damage can just get piled right on top o' the ol' *fireball*.

Comment: Umm... so how would you apply it to *fire storm* (multiple areas)? How about *fire shield*?

Comment: @Hassassin The spell *fire storm* is an area spell that still only affects a lone shapeable area (the spell's cubes are contiguous), and the spell *fire shield* creates one effect, so both would see the *ring*'s full benefit applied to their lone effects (and with *fire shield*, that's pretty awesome). The weird outlier really is *scorching ray*; to find a close-to-comparable spell one needs to use a spell like *energy spheres* (*SpC* 80), and even that doesn't work very well.

Comment: @HeyICanChan, sorry, I was thinking about *firebrand* not *fire storm*. It generates a 5' burst per level, each dealing 1d6 per level (each creature only takes damage from one).

Comment: @Hassassin No problem. I'd allow the *ring* wearer / *firebrand* caster to pick which of the 5-ft. radius shapeable bursts deals the extra damage.  (And that's a much better comparable spell than *energy spheres*!) (And, although *firebrand* is more precise, I prefer *blast of flame* (*SpC* 31); that *SR: No* is awesome.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan, ok, that seems like a consistent (and probably RAW) way to rule it. Just seems unnecessarily complex (but what else is new).

Answer (score 5):

## Yes

If you cast a Fireball for 5d6 and used that ring, every target hit by the fireball would take 10d6 damage (+1d6 from the level up, +4d6 from the effect).

The effect boosts the damage the spell does.  The ring does not state "once".  So when you evaluate damage on the next fire spell you cast, you simply add +4d6.

This is a reasonably strong combo, but it is only damage.  If your 3.5e wizards are dealing damage, they aren't as strong as they could be.

An alternative explaination would be that the damage bonus applies the first time the spell deals fire damage to any target.  So a fireball would deal 6d6 damage, but the first thing damaged would take +4d6 damage.  This +4d6 damage would not be subject to saving throws.  Similarly, the rays would shoot out, and the first target hit (and hence damaged) would take +4d6 damage.  I don't buy it, there are too many choices to make in how exactly this works.

The ability says the next fire spell deals +4d6 damage.  You should take it at its word, at least initially, and check if it breaks the game.

For a sanity check, we'll see how badly this breaks the game.  A level 10 wizard using it hits for 3 rays at 8d6 each, or 84 total damage (touch attack).

Picking 3 random CR 10 creatures, none of them die even if everything hits.  They have over 100 HP.

It isn't one-shotting an even-CR creature.  A wizard could do better: winning a fight against an even-CR creature is what a good spell *does*.  So this isn't a huge balance issue in general.  It could be in your party specifically.

We should also look at how it interact with other fire spells: it is also efficient with flaming sphere (and a way to make them not run away), at 2d6+4d6 damage per round (reflex negates), or flame arrows with archers to help (the arrows deal +5d6 damage *each*), or fire trap (where you pre-cast it when not adventuring for 1d4+level+4d6 damage), fire shield (where it applies to each time it deals damage 5d6+level), or wall of fire with solid fog (or other means to trap foes) for more than one round.

For fast burst, a meteor swarm isn't bad (6d6+4d6 all times 4, for 40d6 damage).

For more fun, Elven Spell Lore on a magic missile to fire damage.  Each one deals 1d4+1+4d6 fire damage, and at level 10 you get 6 of them.  105 damage, no save, no to-hit roll.

And even with that attempt at breaking it, it still isn't the best use of an action.

Comment: Not sure that an altered Magic Missile would work... depends on your reading of "If the spell doesn't *normally* deal fire damage".

Comment: @Adeptus true.  How normal is elven spell lore?  In any case, that is as close as I managed to get to broken: maximized fire magic missile dealing 174 fire damage for no save no to-hit role as a level 4 spell.

Comment: The feat Elven Spell Lore (*PH2* 78-9) says, "When preparing that spell, you can alter the energy type of the damage it deals to some other energy type of your choosing." And, oddly, force isn't an energy type (*RC* 42). Undoubtedly, there's a way to make *magic missile* instead deal one of the five kinds of energy damage (maybe even fire), but the feat Elven Spell Lore doesn't seem to do it. (Of course, if reading *alter* as *change none to fire*, that's a thing.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan First, one 2nd level spell and a daily use of a magic item.  Second, I'm balancing it based off of what wizards *do in game*, not what the designers said they wanted wizards to do in game.  Making wizards balanced based off the assumption that an even-CR foe is *hard* is far beyond the scope of this question, and if you make RAI balance decisions based on that you'll fail, and when you succeed you'll just say "interpret everything in the worst possible light for the wizard to extreme degrees" in *every context*, which seems overly hostile.

Comment: Upon reflection, I'm probably just overthinking things. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

> ... grants a bonus to the amount of damage you deal with the next fire spell you cast ...

The damage is to the *spell* (singular); he would have 4d6 that he could apply across the rays that he has.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is actually that it does +xd6 per target per spell.

So, if you boost it to +4d6, it will deal the additional damage to every target you hit with a Scorching Ray, just like a Fireball would. If you hit the same target with all rays, it only takes the +4d6 once, just like a fireball.

This removes the difference in application between rays/magic missile effects and AoE's for damage boosts, and makes them slightly more effective against multiple opponents, while not overpowering them with additional damage.